# JSON Web Token for Web Service

Tags: json, web-services, rest, token, slim

anyone know about JSON Web Token ? 
I want use that JWT for API KEY in my RESTful Web Service.

I already have function for generating API KEY for every user who registered.
This is the function

`private function generateApiKey() {
        return md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    }`

In that function, I just randomize that Md5 to generate the API KEY.
And I knew that, It would create a risk for my web service as the API KEY continue to be send every user make a request.

So, is there a way to use JWT in my function ?

I'm using SLIM PHP framework anyway :)

Thanks before.

Comment: Why not?

Are you using composer with slim php?

If yes, then jump here and install jwt library https://packagist.org/search/?q=jwt. (note: there are plenty libs there, chose one).

Comment: Actually the result is not a true random string. Use [mcrypt_create_iv](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) instead. Afaik you cannot use java in php, but you might try :D